# How to remove \r\n line breaks in a text file that are within quotes and not the end of the row

Tags: azure, csv, text-files, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a large set of files that contain line breaks within a column that are all wrapped in quotes, but U-SQL cannot process the files because it is seeing the `\r\n` as the end of the row despite being wrapped in quotes.

Is there an easy way to fix these files other than opening each file up individually in something like notepad++?  It seems there should be a way to ignore line breaks if they are contained within quotes.

Example is something like this:
`1,200,400,"123 street","123 street,\r\nNew York, NY\r\nUnited States",\N,\N,200\r\n`

Notepad++ works fine for finding and replacing values manually, but I'm trying to find a batch way to do this because I have multiple files (50+ per source table) and hundreds of thousands of records in each that I need to fix.

Comment: Simple answer is that you could write an algorithm in python or node.js that goes through all the files, opens them, removes the line breaks in between quotes and saves the files. It will take like 15 lines of code in python and will be certainly faster than going through all the files manually.

Comment: I am attempting to do this now in Databricks w/ Python. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then your row is in this way?

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30607/58878816-72e04580-86d4-11e9-93e5-ac66cf5c0c5a.png

Answer (score 1):

According to U-SQL GitHub issue 84: [USQL and embedded newline characters](https://github.com/Azure/usql/issues/84) you can either build a custom extractor, or try to use the `escapeCharacter` parameter of the built-in extractor:

`USING Extractors.Csv(quoting : true, escapeCharacter : '\\') // quoting is true by default, but it does not hurt to repeat.`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, escapeCharacter doesn't provide a working solution for this problem. It seems a custom extractor might work, but it's a whole lot of overhead on a problem I feel should have a much simpler solution.  I will try the custom extractor though if I can't find an easier solution, thanks!